# i have a regular expression that i need to figure out

Tags: ruby, regex, expression

```
"peter,nick,jake,jack"
```

i need to have something like this.

i cannot have any whitespace after the word for example,
`"peter,," "peter," "peter,,nick  "` will all be incorrect.

it has to be just a word such as `"peter"` or a word follow by a comma then word (`"peter,nick"`)

Comment: What do you start with? I get what you want but what do you have?

Comment: Post your non-working solution and people can help you figure out why it's not working and how to correct it.

Comment: i have a string of "peter,nick,jack" and i need it a regex condition to fit this

Comment: sorry, what do u mean by start with

Answer (score 1):

First confirm that the string has the required structure.

```
r = /
    \A                # match the beginning of the string
    [[:alpha:]]+      # match > 0 letters
    (?:,[[:alpha:]]+) # match a comma then > 0 letters in a non-capture group
    *                 # match the preceding non-capture group >= 0 times
    \z                # match end of the string
    /x                # free-spacing regex definition mode

str = "peter,nick,jake,jack"

str =~ r #=> 0
```

Since it matches the regex, simply split on commas to return an array of the words.

```
str.split(',') #=> ["peter", "nick", "jake", "jack"]
```

By contrast:

```
"peter,nick,,jake,jack" =~ r #=> nil
"peter,nick,jake, jack" =~ r #=> nil
"peter,nick,jake,jack " =~ r #=> nil
"peter ispeter,nick"    =~ r #=> nil
```

I assume the string must contain at least one letter.

Comment: thank you, could you explain what dose [:alpha:] do?

Comment: also, could you add more condition to it. such that a word can contain anything but a whitespace. for example "peter ispeter,nick" would be consider wrong because it has a space. "peter-=_-.ispeter,nick" would be correct because it dose not contain any type of space

Comment: Do you mean you would like the regex to match `"peter ispeter,nick"`? What about `"peter ispeter ,nick"` (a space after both `"peter"` and `"ispeter"`)?

Comment: no, "peter ispeter,nick" would be wrong because it has a whitespace, the correct one for this is "peterispeter,nick". the rule is that there can be no space. the only thing separate the words is the comma. any white space with in the string will consider wrong

Comment: As you see, I had added another example to show the there is no match with my regex when there is an embedded space.